# How to ingest csv files with different columns into the same Redshift table using AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a Spark script that will ingest a bunch of csv files (in S3) into a Redshift table.

Depending on where the csv file came from, it will have different columns. There are twenty possible columns. Every csv file will always contain the first ten and some number of the last 10.

I want to write an AWS Glue job to automate this ingestion to take a csv file and insert into the Redshift table that contains all twenty possible column headers.

I've tried first converting these into parquet format with Glue but it gets the schema wrong. It ends up, somehow, creating parquet files with hundreds of column headers. Not sure how this is possible.